# Hazelcast deserializes value on server on get from Binary IMap

Tags: java, deserialization, hazelcast

We have an application connecting as client to cluster of Hazelcast servers. Hazelcast version used is 5.1 on both client and servers.
We have a `IMap<Long, Product>` that has been populated previously without problem to the cluster. But when we try to retrieve a value from the `IMap`, it results in an exception

```
ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 1
...
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 1
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:139)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)

(the get on IMap is during @PostConstruct, that's why "Error creating bean with name 'application'").
```

The `Product` class representing the value is implementing the IdentifiedDataSerializable and has **on client** associated and correctly registered ProductDataSerializableFactory (implements DataSerializableFactory).

The thing is that this exception is NOT originating on the client - it comes from the Hazelcast grid. And that is the issue - because the `IMap` is defined as BINARY - hence the server should NOT care about `DataSerializerFactory`, it should simply pass the bytes to the client and let it do the deserialization. So why it is not working as we expect? What might be wrong? And speaking about, how can we register the the above mentioned factory on server as well?

I'm attaching the relevant part of `HazelcastConfiguration` Java file used on client and `hazelcast.xml` used on servers below (omitted the unimportant parts like join etc.). It is mostly a default one with some additions, e.g. `user-code-deployment`. `HazelcastConfiguration` on client

```java
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.getSerializationConfig().addDataSerializableFactoryClass(ProductDataSerializableFactory.FACTORY_ID, ProductDataSerializableFactory.class);
    ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig = new ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
    clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass("com.finmason.product.Product");
    clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass("com.finmason.product.ProductDataSerializableFactory");
    clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);    
    config.setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig);    
    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
}
```

`hazelcast.yml` on server

```yaml
hazelcast:
  user-code-deployment:
    enabled: true
    class-cache-mode: ETERNAL
    provider-mode: LOCAL_AND_CACHED_CLASSES
    whitelist-prefixes: com.finmason
    provider-filter: HAS_ATTRIBUTE:lite
  security:
    client-block-unmapped-actions: true
  map:
    default:
      in-memory-format: BINARY
      metadata-policy: CREATE_ON_UPDATE          
  serialization:
    portable-version: 0
  jet:
    enabled: true
    resource-upload-enabled: true
```

And the source of `ProductDataSerializableFactory`

```java
public class ProductDataSerializableFactory implements DataSerializableFactory {
    public static final int FACTORY_ID = 1;
    public static final int PRODUCT_TYPE = 1;

    @Override
    public IdentifiedDataSerializable create(int typeId) {
        return (typeId == PRODUCT_TYPE) ? new Product() : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `1` the id of your factory? Can you share the full stacktrace (or the relevant part in `com.hazelcast`..)

Comment: yes, the factory id is 1. added source of the class to the description. I'll reproduce it again and add more of the stack as well

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately, it doesn't help much. Is there more by any chance? It should look somewhat like this https://gist.githubusercontent.com/frant-hartm/5f65c1de2ff5a5428ff7f4af4191cad8/raw/2505934226f6cc79ee1ec1287816eb59c312b65e/hazelcast-exception

Comment: managed to reproduce the exact issue. full stacktrace up to the point in our code is here https://gist.github.com/ismajstrla/e2f35d781794178cadebe8fb48dc7704 . Hope it does help :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce it - what I tried: in client-server deployment, add entries from the client, serialized using IdentifiedDataSerializable, then calling forEach on the map. I am happy to look further into it if you provide a reproducer.